# How much does the formal completion know about the ambient variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, formal-schemes, ample-bundles

How much information does the formal completion along an ample divisor hold about the ambient variety? Given two smooth projective varieties such that they have isomorphic ample divisors, where the formal completion along the two are isomorphic, what can be said about the two varieties?

As mentioned in comments blowing-up a point not on the divisor is an example that produces such two varieties.

Let's consider the equivalence relation generated by the relation expressed in the first paragraph. Is there any interesting description of the varieties mod this equivalence relation? (Or even maybe any interesting examples)

Let's assume dimension of the varieties are greater than or equal to $3$.

Comment: Blowing up a point that is not on the divisor shows that they don't need to be the same. I have no idea if I expect them to be birational in general.

Comment: A formal completion of any curve at a smooth point should give the same result, and of course two curves needn't be birational

Comment: @Wojowu let's assume dimension is at least $3$.

Comment: For two curves $C,C'$ consider divisors $\{p\}\times\mathbb P^2,\{p'\}\times\mathbb P^2$ in $C\times\mathbb P^2,C'\times\mathbb P^2$ respectively, where $p\in C,p'\in C'$ are some points.

Comment: Are those divisors ample? I'm thinking in terms of Nakai Moishezon criterion. It seems you can find curves that doesn't intersect the divisors or maybe I'm confused ...

Comment: Apologies, I didn't think twice when writing my second comment. Of course they won't be ample in general.